# Is it possible to convert a base64 SVG into a standard one that uses paths / <g> tags?

Tags: svg

I have an SVG that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="3367px" height="1250px" viewBox="0 0 3367 1250" enable-background="new 0 0 3367 1250" xml:space="preserve">  <image id="image0" width="3367" height="1250" x="0" y="0"
    xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAADScAAATiCAQAAABYVH+tAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJN
AAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAAAmJLR0QA/4ePzL8AAAAJcEhZ
cwAALiMAAC4jAXilP3YAAAAHdElNRQfkBRkBOx8UiOyrAABwDUlEQVR42uzda5obq5Io0PT5el6m
RlZ4ZEqPzP3Du/b2o+wSEhnBYy19t0/f07gACaXIDAKOAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAADgKp+yGwDAxepf/m+fj/Lv/34eXx/6GwAAAADA4oSTANZQfggMvV5a05d//7ea3WkAAAAA
IIJwEsCc6j//eW3o6D5vAab6zB8BAAAAAEYlnAQwi+/5Rz9uTzem78Glmt0MAAAAAKAX4SSAkc0S
QvqTL8dxnMeZ3QwAAAAA4BnCSQDj+R5EGmEbu36+HDKWAAAAAGBSwkkA46jHzJlI9zmPr/KVAAAA
AGAuwkkA2VbMRfqYsBIAAAAATEM4CSBPXT4X6WM2wYNs9eF/KSQ8v7L9rxCMaYfraw2sa4f3k93V
h/+l7wcAAAytHvX45vXTq3qkCSmeuxoxO79GXl5jvmr2xSGA9xP6eeb3/JbdeABm8r/sBgBspBz1
uB3fjtfttrb72OtxOwSVIN7np/51zW4+AMD2nrm7lKkMQAPhJIAI5ajHt+N2vJqs/5WgEsR69gGC
0DgAQK765L83nwPgbsJJANf6L5DEvQSVIMrzV6aS3QUAgK09O5+TnwTA3YSTAK4ikPQcQSW4Xnn6
L7jCAQDkKYP8DQC2IJwE0J9AUj9vQSWgv9rhb1jPCgCQp8c9p/tWAO4knATQk0DSNV6Pb8fNQ2vo
rM+VyvUOACBHr4U9NbsjAMxBOAmgl3rcBJIuVOQpQVe1098p2R0BANhU6fR33MUCcJf/y24AwALK
```

Is it possible to conver that into a standard SVG that uses `<path>` and `<g>` tags that we are all familiar with ?

What is that standard SVG called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is a way of converting a stream of binary data into printable characters (letters, numbers, and punctuation) for when you can't include arbitrary binary data.

SVG is already printable, so encoding it with Base64 wouldn't make any sense; there is no "base64 SVG" here.

What you're seeing is *something else* embedded *inside* the SVG. A clue to *what* is embedded comes in this line:

```
data:image/png;base64
```

That's a [data: URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), but the important thing to notice is that as well as "base64", it specifies a file type: "image/png". So the thing that's embedded is a [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) file - a bitmap image format common on the web.

This explains two things:

- It needs to be base64 encoded, because it's a binary format embedded into a text format.
- It needs to be embedded, because it's a bitmap image (specifying the colour of each pixel) not a vector image (specifying what shapes to draw).

So, in short: no.